# How to return data from a WebApi using HttpClient

Tags: vb.net, http-post, httpclient, webapi

I have been trying without success to return data from a an internally developed WebApi.  The API uses Post requests to return data the body of the request containing complex criteria.  I have previously had success using a Post Request to write data via the API, but I seem to have hit a brick wall in my efforts to return data.  Here is the method I have been using:

```
 Public Async Function Request(ByVal client As HttpClient, ByVal content As String) As Task

      Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)
      Dim byteContent = New ByteArrayContent(buffer)
      byteContent.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")

      Dim response = Await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, byteContent)
      Dim result As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
      _result = result

 End Function
```

For conveninence the results are stored in a class variable, which enables me to test the routine using MSTest.  The function should return a JSON array however it doesn't even return an error, rather it just returns Nothing.

Here is the associated TestMethod:

```
 <TestMethod()> Public Sub ShouldSuccessfullyInterrodateTheSpenHapi()

      Dim da = New SPEN.ODSDataPackagerService
      Dim crit As New HttpCriterion
      Dim stopped As Boolean
      Dim jsonString As String = Nothing

      crit.StartTime = "2022-11-03T00:00:00"
      crit.EndTime = "2022-11-03T00:30:00"
      crit.Interval = "30m"
      crit.TagAttribute = "InstrumentTag"
      crit.TagFilter = "confidential"
      crit.Delimiter = "~"
      crit.ServerName = "SPRODA"

      'Deserialize object to JSON
      jsonString = da.GetCriteriaJson(crit)


      Try
           da.InitialiseSettings()
           da.Request(da.Clients(0), jsonString)
           Debug.Print(da.Result)
           Assert.IsTrue(True)
      Catch ex As Exception
           Assert.IsTrue(False)
      End Try

 End Sub
```

What am I missing guys?

EDIT:

Ok some further experimentation with the following code, I am at least now getting an error:

```
 Public Async Function GetVoltagesFromPI(ByVal client As HttpClient, ByVal content As String) As Task(Of PIItemList)
      Dim piItems As PIItemList = New PIItemList
      Dim buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)
      Dim byteContent = New ByteArrayContent(buffer)
      byteContent.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")

      Try
           Dim response As New HttpResponseMessage
           response = Await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, byteContent)

           If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                _result = New PIItemList
                _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
           End If
      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      Finally

      End Try

 End Function
```

The function errors at:

```
 response = Await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, byteContent)
```

with:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block
```

But really I am no further forward with regards a solution as far as I can make out the code should work, but there is obviously smething flawed in the code implementation.

Kind Regards
Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Finally...  Managed to get things working, here is the bare bones working code.  Would appreciate any additional input though:

```
 ''' <summary>
 '''  Request pi data via the specified http endpoint (baseaddress)
 ''' </summary>
 ''' <param name="client"></param>
 ''' <param name="content"></param>
 Public Function GetVoltagesFromPI(ByVal client As HttpClient, ByVal content As String) As Task(Of PIItemList)

      Dim requestMsg As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress)
      Dim response As HttpResponseMessage
      Dim interim As Object

      Try
           requestMsg.Content = New StringContent(content, Text.UTF8Encoding.Default, "application/json")
           response = client.SendAsync(requestMsg).Result
           If (response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
                _resultSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
           End If
      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      Finally

      End Try

 End Function
```